# How to set a pdf Field uneditable in iTextSharp

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, textfield

as the title says i´ve got to fill text fields with data (what works perfectly) an make the fields uneditable.

I tried to achieve that using

form.SetFieldProperty(key, key, TextField.READ_ONLY, Nothing)

but I dont know what to put in as the last parameter and that line actually didnt do anything for me. Another thing I tried to do was

form.RemoveField(key)

but that removed the field including the text so I had a blank pdf.

I have been looking for a solution now and then for quite a while now and i couldnt find anything to help me out in no tutorial or documentation. Im actually quite surprised no one asked for that functionality before. Is it really because no one needs this funktion? Or is it because its so easy or obviously impossible using iTextSharp?

(Sorry for doublepost, I just realized my title did not secify my problem properly)

Answer (score 0):

That last param should be null for the vast majority of cases.

http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setFieldProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int[])

And StackOverflow doesn't like () or [] in its links.  Annoying.

And it's not `key, key`, it's

```
form.SetFieldProperty(fldName, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
```

There are also a number of annotation flags defined in PdfAnnotation that need to be set thusly:

```
form.SetFieldProperty(fldName, "setflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAG_*, null);
```

Note that there's PdfAnnotation.FLAG_READONLY, and PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY.  I only set FF_READ_ONLY, but it couldn't hurt to set the other one as well... or could it!?

Check the [JavaDoc](http://api.itextpdf.com/).  There is quite a bit of iText Info In iThere.